# access photo library on the iPad using Xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, camera, xcode4.3

I am able to access the iPhone Photo library with the following code.  What do I need to add to access the photo library on the iPad.  I know it has to do with a UIPopOver but don't know how to implement it.

```
- (void) useCamera
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                              nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker
                            animated:YES];

    newMedia = YES;
}
}


- (void) useCameraRoll
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                              nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    newMedia = NO;
}
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *mediaType = [info
                       objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = [info
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    imageView.image = image;
    if (newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                       self,

@selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    // Code here to support video if enabled
}
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                          message: @"Failed to save image"\
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];    
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that has worked for me in an existing application that supports both iPhone and iPad:

Note: the SSiOSUtilities is a class I created that has code to determine if you are on an iPad or iPhone.

```
- (IBAction)fromCamera:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:YES];

    if ([SSiOSUtilities isIPad])
    {
        UIPopoverController *tempPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        [tempPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:[[self cameraButton] frame] inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        [self setPopOver:tempPopOver];
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }

    [picker release];
}

- (IBAction)fromLibrary:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:YES];

    if ([SSiOSUtilities isIPad])
    {
        UIPopoverController *tempPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        [tempPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:[[self libraryButton] frame] inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        [self setPopOver:tempPopOver];
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }

    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    if ([SSiOSUtilities isIPad])
    {
        [[self popOver] dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [[self popOver] release];
    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // rest of code for image here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I use. It creates a UIImagePickerController, then uses it as the content view controller for a UIPopoverController. The variable vc is declared in the .h and is a UIPopoverController.

NOTE: iOS 7 just came out and I have found that when I run this code, the screen darkens slightly as if to display the photo library, but the popover controller does not show up.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    if (vc == nil)  //show the popover if it is not being displayed
    {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        vc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [vc presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:chooseButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    }
    else    //hide the popover if it is already being displayed
    {
        [vc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        vc = nil;
    }
}
```